# ValueRequired Exception While using Simple-XML-Framework

Tags: android, simple-framework

I am trying to use Simple-XML-framework. But i am getting ValueRequiredException

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=, inline=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'Employees' public java.util.List com.example.xmlparsing.Company.Employees for class com.example.xmlparsing.Company at line 2
```

My XML file has the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company>
<Emp>
    <Name>Venkat</Name>
    <ID>661511</ID>  
</Emp>
<Emp>
    <Name>Shiv</Name>
    <ID>661311</ID> 
</Emp>
</Company>
```

My Annotation classes are as follows :

Company.java :

```
package com.example.xmlparsing;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Company {

@ElementList
public List<Emp> Employees;

}
```

Emp.java :

```
package com.example.xmlparsing;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Text;

@Element(name="Emp")
public class Emp {

@Element
public String Name;

@Element
public String ID;


}
```

What could be the problem? how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your Code:

First, you need `@Root()` instead of `@Element` at `Emp` class:

```
@Root(name="Emp")
public class Emp {

@Element
public String Name;

@Element
public String ID;


}
```

Second, if you use a list that way:

```
@Root
public class Company {

@ElementList
public List<Emp> Employees;

}
```

its wrapped into another xml tag.
You can either *change your xml* or simply use `@ElementList(inline = true)`.

Comment: How to get this kind of Array 
<DownloadableFormats>
                      <Name>test</Name>
 <Name>test1</Name>
<Name>test2</Name>
 <Name>test3</Name>
                   </DownloadableFormats>

I am getting this exception 
Element ' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(name=, type=void, data=false, required=true) on field 'name' private java.lang.String

Comment: Use `@ElementList` with `inline=true`.